# How to specify the dependency of each source file on its corresponding header file by using wild cards?

Tags: c++, makefile

Should be a simple makefile question, but didn't find a solution after some quick surfing.

Basically I have a bunch of "cpp" codes, each of which has a corresponding header file with the same stem name. I want to specify the dependency of each source file on its corresponding header file by using wild cards. The last commented-out line is what I want to add, and apparently its not working as intended.

```
SOURCES=a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp
HEADERS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.h)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.cpp
     $(CC) -fPIC -c $< -o $@

#$(OBJECTS): $(HEADERS)
```

Comment: How about: `%.o: %.cpp %.h`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this:

```
$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.h
```

or modify your rule:

```
$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.cpp %.h
    $(CC) -fPIC -c $< -o $@
```